# Google Cloud SQL replication - Slave doesn't allow passwords

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I followed Google's guide [Configuring Replication with Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/replication) to have a replication between these 2 elements:

1. Master. The Google Cloud SQL instance. Which is supposed to be a modified, but still compatible, MySQL version by Google.
2. Slave. Standard MySQL version `5.5.35-0+wheezy1` running on Debian 7 Wheezy. This is on an instance of Google Compute Engine.

All the setup when smoothly and the slave is working, but all the users on the slave are not working with passwords. Every user is functional but they can be accessed without passwords which of course is an undesired behavior.

Any idea on how to get the slave working with the same user/passwords as the master?

Note: This would be more appropriate for Server Fault, but I've seen this tag way more active on SO, even with platform-only questions, so I hope this can stay here.

Comment: Why prevents you from setting passwords for the users on the slave?

Comment: @RazvanMusaloiu-E. setting the passwords on the slave doesn't work either. Nor creating a new user with a new pass. It ignores them always.

Comment: The queries to change/add users on slave fail? I presume you do a 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' before expecting them to become live.

Comment: @RazvanMusaloiu-E. Yeah I do flush privileges before testing them. The users are created successfully too, nevertheless they don't work.